# Write the functions with the given domain and range

Tags: education

Domain $\mathbb{R}$, range the set of reals $\geq k$ where $k$ is a given constant.

Domain = $\{ x \mid x \in \mathbb{R} \}$. How would I write the range?

Answer (score 1):

They have already told you the domain and range. If you're used to seeing the range in set builder notation, it is:
$$
\{y \in \Bbb R \mid y \geq k\}
$$

---

**Hint:** To come up with a function that has this domain and range, consider a parabola.

Comment: would that be given the formula for a function given that domain and range?

Comment: Yes. You are asked to come up with a function (there is more than one answer) that has the given domain and range.